# Syntax error near unexpected token 'newline'?

Tags: vim

I have the following written in my .vimrc file

```
set number 

set hlsearch

set mouse=a

map F2 :bprev CR
```

Getting follwoing error while sourcing .vimrc file

```
-bash: .vimrc: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
-bash: .vimrc: line 4: `map <F2> :bprev <CR>'
```

Comment: `.vimrc` isn't a shell script; it's a `vim` script.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+bash%3A+.vimrc+syntax+error+near+unexpected+token

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.vimrc` isn't a shell script; it's a `vim` script. Both programs have a `set` command (though each does something very different than the other), which is how you get to line 4 at all. The problem here is that the shell sees the `<` and `>` as redirection operators, and the final `>` is followed by a newline, not a file name; hence, the syntax error.

Comment: How do I then source my .vimrc as vim script ?

Comment: You source it *in* `vim` itself. `.vimrc`, specifically, is sourced by `vim` when `vim` starts.